# List a value in a table asynchronously that comes from another object

Tags: reactjs

I've been struggling with this for a week.

I have a page thats prints me a table with values:

```
name             resource_group          

Machine-1         Group-1
Machine-2         Group-2
Machine-3         Group-3
```

This values are from a map that i do over a Json Object like this:

```
data = [
        {"name": "Machine-1", "resource_group": "Group-1"},
        {"name": "Machine-2",   "resource_group": "Group-2"}, 
        {"name": "Machine-3",   "resource_group": "Group-3"}
       ]
```

Now i want to add a status value foreach of this machines, async, so when the page loads, it will load with the previous table plus a status for each machine.
I searched and tried foreach loop and for loops but i' can t find a way to do it.

The output should be something like this:

```
name             resource_group      status      

Machine-1         Group-1              on
Machine-2         Group-2              off
Machine-3         Group-3              off
```

To get the status value i have another Json Object:

```
MachineRow = [
              {"name": Machine-1,  "status": "on"},
              {"name": Machine-2,  "status": "off"}, 
              {"name": Machine-3,  "status": "off"}
             ]
```

They have in common the name so i was trying to work with that.

This is what i have so far that works, but in the wrong way because the status gets listed 3 times for each line:

```
return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <h1>Azure machines</h1>
      <Table className={classes.table} size="small">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell align="left">name</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">resource_group</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">location</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">status</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {data.map(row => (
            <TableRow key={row.name + row.resource_group}>
              <TableCell align="left" component="th" scope="row">
                <StyledButton size = "small" className={style.size3}>
                     <Link  style={{ color: 'inherit', textDecoration: 'inherit'}} to={`/machines/${row.resource_group + "/" + row.name}`}>{row.name}</Link>
                  </StyledButton>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left">{row.resource_group}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left">{row.location}</TableCell>
                {MAchineRow.map(row => (
               <TableCell  key= {row.name + row.resource_group}align="left">
                 <MachineStatusIcon
                  status_code={row.status_code}
                  status={row.status}
            />
               </TableCell>
           ))}
          </TableRow>
         ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>

    </div>
  )
}
```

The output of this return is this:

```
name             resource_group       status      

Machine-1         Group-1              on          off        off
Machine-2         Group-2              on          off        off
Machine-3         Group-3              on          off        off
```

How can i manage to print the right status for each machine, without merging objects, one by line?
Can it be done inside the return?
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't use map, use find.

instead of

```
{MAchineRow.map(row => (
               <TableCell  key= {row.name + row.resource_group}align="left">
                 <MachineStatusIcon
                  status_code={row.status_code}
                  status={row.status}
            />
               </TableCell>
           ))}
```

try something like this:

```
<TableCell key={row.name + row.resource_group) align='left'>
    <MachineStatusIcon
          status_code={MachineRow.find( ({ name }) => name === row.name).status}
          status={MachineRow.find( ({ name }) => name === row.name).status}
    />
  </TableCell>
```

Comment: Hi @Wen, like that it  fires the error "Cannot read property 'status_code' of undefined". It does not find the property because it's not mapped i guess.

Comment: You didn't list the code for that component, so I just assumed you have it defined in the MachinesStatusIcon component. You can just remove that.

Comment: No, the Machine status Icon only changes the values to an icon green or red for on and off status... To get the status i need to make a map, like was before, but if i do the map it prints 3 in a row with you code as well.

Comment: you don't need another map for the status, you need to use find. The data.map already giving you all the rows.

Comment: yes ,normally it should because find returns the first element that satisfies the condition, but it's not finding any value...

Comment: I've updated the code to this `{MachinesRow > 0 && MachinesRow.find( ({ name }) => name === row.name).status_code}
                        {MachinesRow > 0 && MachinesRow.find( ({ name }) => name === row.name).status}` , because the fetch returns first an empty array but it's the same, it does get the value

Comment: should probably be 'machinesRow.length > 0`. so it's working or no?

Comment: Yes bro, i was missing the length, it works now without the icon component wrapping it up, now i need to make it work with the component :)

Comment: Ok i manage to put it working with the component, thanks a lot @WenHaoWu, you saved my life :)